# Symfony ACL: updateObjectAce() Indexing Errors

Tags: symfony, acl, access-control

I have the following function in a Symfony service that is supposed to update an entity's ACL for a given user:

```
public function editPermission($user, $entity){
    $allEntities = $this->em->getRepository($entity)->findAll();

    /**
     * ACLs grant user permission on every instance of each entity.
     * In order to edit permissions across all of these entites for each user,
     * first iterate over all entities. 
     * For each entity, update the permission for the specified user.
     */
    foreach($allEntities as $oneEntity){
      // locate the ACL
      $objectIdentity = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($oneEntity);
      $acl = $this->aclProvider->findAcl($objectIdentity);

      // update user access
      $entityId = $objectIdentity->getIdentifier();

      $objectAces = $acl->getObjectAces();
      for ($i=(sizeof($objectAces)-1); $i>=0; $i--){
          $acl->updateObjectAce($objectAces[$i], MaskBuilder::MASK_DELETE); 
      }
      $this->aclProvider->updateAcl($acl);
    }

    return true;
  }
```

I currently have only two entries in my 'acl_entries' table. While iterating through the $objectAces, I get the notice:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0
```

Now, let's say I change my updateObjectAce index to '1' instead of $objectAces[$i]. When I do this, the first record's mask updates, but I get the error:

```
The index "1" does not exist.
```

If I change the updateObjectAce index to '2', the second record does NOT update and I get the error:

```
The index "2" does not exist.
```

Is there some weird way the ACLs update that I'm missing here?

Comment: I'd recommend using voters. They're much easier to understand and use. There is very [nice and simple presentation about this](http://slides.com/marieminasyan/drop-ace-use-role-voters#/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the same situation described in [this comment](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5820#issuecomment-9922749) and fix in [this manner](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5820#issuecomment-9923445).
Try this:

```
$objectAces = $acl->getObjectAces();
foreach($aces as $i => $ace) {
          $acl->updateObjectAce($i, MaskBuilder::MASK_DELETE); 
      }
```

Instead of this:

```
$objectAces = $acl->getObjectAces();
for ($i=(sizeof($objectAces)-1); $i>=0; $i--){
          $acl->updateObjectAce($objectAces[$i], MaskBuilder::MASK_DELETE); 
      }
```

Hope this help

Comment: Interesting! Any idea why the foreach works when the for doesn't? Do the ACL indexes change after each call to updateObjectAce()? I did try reversing the for loop as someone had suggested in that thread but that didn't work either.

Comment: i don't know... try dumping the $i value inside the foreach and see what value have... probably is no not a number?

Comment: Yeah I did that and I only get one of the $i values; the second one never shows up even if I do something like get rid of the -1 in 'sizeof($objectAces[$i]) -1'